# Php redirect not working on submission

Tags: php, wordpress, csv

I'm trying to redirect to another page once a csv has been generated by a clicking the submit button. So far, when i click the button it sends the CSV and it gives me the message "Success" which makes me think it's working well.

However, what i really want the page to redirect after the submission has been made. I've added header(location: ) within the else statement but it's not doing anything.

Can anyone help me please?

```
    if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {

    function send_csv_mail ($csvData, $body, $to = 'email@email.co.uk', $subject = 'Test email with attachment', $from = 'webmaster@example.com') {

    global $post;
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

      // This will provide plenty adequate entropy
      $multipartSep = '-----'.md5(time()).'-----';

      // Arrays are much more readable
      $headers = array(
        "From: $from",
        "Reply-To: $from",
        "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$multipartSep\""
      );

      // Make the attachment
      $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(create_csv_string($csvData))); 

      // Make the body of the message
      $body = "--$multipartSep\r\n"
            . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1; format=flowed\r\n"
            . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n"
            . "\r\n"
            . "$body\r\n"
            . "--$multipartSep\r\n"
            . "Content-Type: text/csv\r\n"
            . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"
            . "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".date('Y-m-d')."-".str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower(get_user_meta($user_id, "wpcf-branch-active", true)))."-file.csv\"\r\n"
            . "\r\n"
            . "$attachment\r\n"
            . "--$multipartSep--";

       // Send the email, return the result
       return @mail($to, $subject, $body, implode("\r\n", $headers)); 

    }

    $array = array(
                    array("Code", "Product Category", "Product Family", "Description", "Quantity", "Bay"),          
    );



    send_csv_mail($array, "Hello World!!!\r\n This is simple text email message.");



    if(!send_csv_mail) {
         echo "Error"; 
    }
    else {
        echo "success";
   Header("Location: somewhere.php");
    die();
    }



    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think this is the best solution I always use it:**
This is a common problem: 
use HTML redirect like below:

```
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; url=./somewhere.php\" />";
```

If you use this way. you can also set time to redirect like if you want to wait for 1 sec you can write like below.

```
 echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"1; url=./somewhere.php\" />";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't send data to the client/buffer and then set an header, because the header was already sent.
Remove `echo "success";` and it will work.
You can use `ob_clean()` to clean the buffer too, check here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-clean.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use WordPress redirect function

```
wp_redirect( $url );
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to end your PHP tag after success, and then use:

```
<script>
location.replace("somewhere.php");
</script>
```

and then pick up your PHP tag to catch your closing brackets.

While this is JavaScript, for your purposes, it will work brilliantly everytime.